# Sharing browser automation scripts without client side installation

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I want to write a browser automation script which can be used by others to perform their mundane tasks easily. For example, a script that will login to a site using provided credentials, select few products ( passed as parameter) and put them into the cart and checkout automatically.

I would like to keep the end-user installation easy and light. Don't want the end user (who is not tech-savy) to download and setup anything.

I had tried Selenium webdriver in Java for this. The script part works perfect for the requirement but asking the end user to install and set up JAVA, etc is not possible.

Would like to know if there is any simple way to achieve this. Preferably an open source solution, but not necessary. Goal is ease of setup and use for the end user.

Can anything similar be done for Android also?

Comment: I have run into the same issue and solved it by creating console apps using C#. As long as your end users are on Windows, you should be able to give them a zip file with an EXE that they can run and supporting Selenium DLLs. I found trying to give others Java-based tools a pain and basically gave up because it's so much easier using C#.

Comment: End user is concerned about virus when they see .EXE etc. I was looking at javascript based approach http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162305/JavaScript-Based-Automated-Testing-for-Web-Applica . The problem here is cross domain java script.  My goal is to make this as a product to be used by thousands of users and hence want to have end-user experience and I am ready to go to any extend to implement this.

Comment: Ah... I assumed you were writing a tool for your coworkers, not external clients. Smart users should be concerned about viruses no matter what the delivery method... javascript is not immune to viruses. If you had the time, money, and expertise, you could provide the UI on a webpage and run the automation on your backend servers... maybe through browserstack or something similar. You could provide the code on github, etc. and also provide an EXE. Anyway... lots of things for you to think about and decide on... good luck

Comment: Thanks @JeffC . I know the task is difficult as I need to have nice user-experience for the end user. I am also exploring appium for android, but looks like all the tests are invoked from the IDE.